# C++ programs on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I just got a new MacBook Pro latest edition.  I noticed that I already have G++ installed on it because of which I am able to build C++ programs.

My question is, does macOS come installed with G++ (because I read online that it comes with a clang compiler) or does G++ need to be installed.  Also note that I have not installed XCode either.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is asking about what software comes bundles with a given computer or OS. It's off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Besides, by default if Clang or the Xcode IDE is installed, the `gcc` and `g++` commands usually are aliases for invoking the corresponding Clang frontend.

Comment: Try `gcc —version`. Most likely it will identify itself as clang.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, but aren't Clang and G++ _different_?  It's like DuckDuckGo calling Google for searching on the web?

Comment: Stack Overflow tries to stay focused on code related questions, other topics can end up leading to debate, to subjective opinion-based recommendations, which really doesn't fit this specific question-answer format. Ideally you have a question that can be answered with code, and has a specific *technical* solution. If not, it's probably best addressed to another forum, or possibly the chat rooms.

Comment: In any case, back to the point: As people already said, check that your g++ is actually g++ and not a symlink for clang++ by running `g++ --version` and checking if it says GCC or Clang.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ... which will reveal it's clang ;) I have done some quick research before on that and all the posts on the topic I found online installed clang. Maybe there's some way to do it though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you.  Yes, it does say Clang after that command.  But [this page by Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html) apparently says that Clang and G++ are different.  What about that?

Comment: @J.Doe tadman's answer explains everything. Yes they're different compilers, it's just that on Mac by default instead of a gcc you get a mere symlink to clang left here for compatibility. It works because clang was designed as an easy replacement for gcc - it has similar flags, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default macOS installation will include something that *pretends* to be `gcc` but that's just a legacy concern so that portable programs will properly detect a compiler when you do a source install with the usual `./configure && make && make install` or use a package manager like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Xcode used to use `gcc` as a back-end prior to `clang` being production-ready. When this switch was done a `gcc` work-alike stub was introduced. As far as I know this just takes `gcc`-style options and forwards them to `clang`.

While GCC and the LLVM [clang project](http://www.llvm.org) are two different things, the `gcc` *command* is not necessarily attached the GCC compiler.

Many programs masquerade as others for historical reasons. `sendmail` also comes with macOS but this is a wrapper for [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org). The Safari browser identifies itself as "Mozilla" even though it has nothing in common with the Mozilla codebase. You'll see these various compatibility stubs all over the place if you look close enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But [this page by Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html) apparently says that Clang and G++ are different.  What about that?

Comment: The `gcc` *command* does not have to be attached to the GCC compiler. I've explained this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If g++ is present, it will compile c++ code.

You will need to issue g++ --version to find out which versin of the compiler you have.

On my mac, g++ --version lets me know that I have apple's clang-900.0.37.

In the end, you will likely need to install Xcode to get very far.